# Oracle Apex cascading checkboxes

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

i need a solution for this "conventionally" mean using apex native functionality.
I have two cascading check boxes when i select any or multiple value from the parent checkbox then the referenced values in checkbox 2 should return (this is working) but when deselect all the values from parent checkbox it should return all the value in checkbox 2.
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=119345:15
help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use NVL in your input item.

```
SELECT DEPTNO || '-' || ENAME, EMPNO 
FROM EMP 
WHERE DEPTNO IN 
      (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE 
         FROM TABLE(APEX_STRING.SPLIT(NVL(:P15_CB1,DEPTNO),':'))) 
ORDER BY 1
```

Ex. https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=145797:3

login on: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=4550:1

```
workspace: stackquestions
user: test
pwd: test
app: 145797
page: 3
```

Comment: this will work if go from top to bottom , but i need filters chained to each other mean no matter which filter i select the others should get filter.

Comment: I can see an error with your example page, is this what you are talking about. Sorry I didn't understand your last comment, I updated my answer, See the example page, I create a dynamic action to refresh the item. Check how I did in that workspace.

Comment: the account is locked :(